# How to get WP to use EST Timezone

Tags: timezones

In my settings, I have New York defined as the time zone. But when I run plugins using PHP date() functions, I am getting a time zone of UTC as it shows in WP Admin > Settings > General.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** Here's the mu-plugin I use to add the meta tag:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Web Services Global Meta Tag(s)
 * Plugin URI: http://example.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/global-metatag-insertion.php
 * Description: This plugin fires on every page and post in the WordPress Multisite Network. It adds custom meta tags to meets our needs. One meta tag that is added is for `last-modified` date.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: me
 * Author URI: http://me.example.com/
 */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Direct access not allowed' );

/**
 * Insert `last-modified` date meta within `<head></head>` container
 */
function last_modified_date() {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="' . date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime( get_the_date() .' ' . get_the_time() ) ) . '" />' . "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'last_modified_date' );
```

Comment: Could you please post that part that adds the `meta` tag? You probably just use the wrong function and make no use of the actual option set in the admin UI.

Comment: Yes, you are probably echoing the server time. Try with [`current_time`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time).

Comment: I added your plugin as [edit] to your answer. Please keep in mind that things that belong to a question should be put into the question – not in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`date()` is unreliable in WP since it always resets time zone to UTC and uses its own processing for time zones.

`date_i18n()` is usually preferable WP replacement, *but* it will also localize output, which might be unwanted.

What you want for correct unlocalized output is to:

1. Get data out of WP API without its offset silliness.
2. Get timezone setting out of WP.
3. Feed those into `DateTime` object.

Here is brief (read it basics, not covering all possibilities) introduction to code:

```
d( date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime( get_the_date() .' ' . get_the_time() ) ) );
// Sat, 07 Jan 2012 07:07:00 UTC < wrong, date() is always wrong in WP

d( date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', get_the_time('U') ) );
// Sat, 07 Jan 2012 07:07:21 UTC < more short, still wrong

d( date_i18n( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', get_the_time('U') ) );
// or simply
d( get_the_time( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T' ) );
// Сб, 07 Jan 2012 07:07:21 EEST < correct! but localized

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( DATE_W3C, get_the_date( DATE_W3C ) );
d( $date->format( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T' ) );
// Sat, 07 Jan 2012 07:07:21 GMT+0300 < correct, but meh numeric time zone

$timezone = new DateTimeZone( get_option( 'timezone_string' ) );
$date->setTimezone( $timezone );

d( $date->format( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T' ) );
// Sat, 07 Jan 2012 06:07:21 EET < correct and not localized
```

I wrote more on topic in my [DateTime crash course for WordPress developers](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/datetime-crash-course/) post.

PS EEST / EET out of sync... I don't even know what's up with that difference. :)

Comment: ps: `d()` is a custom wrapper for `var_dump()`  ?

Comment: Yeah, it's Kint dumper.

Answer (score 2):

### Headers

First off: The `http-equiv` meta tags are the HTML **equiv**alent of an HTTP response header. They **can not** override a header already sent by your web server. So their only use is as a fallback and they rarely provide any real help. In reality, you want to go in and fix the headers your server(s) is/are sending instead – or ask your host to do so if you are in a shared environment and are not allowed to do so.

### Date and Time options

All those can be retrieved via: `get_option( 'name' );`. The possible values are:

- Time format: `time_format` – default: `__('g:i a')` (string)
- Time zone: `timezone_string` – default: `null` (string)
- Date format: `date_format` – default: `__('F j, Y')` (string)
- GMT Offset: `gmt_offset` – default: `date('Z') / 3600` (integer)

Then there are several other possible functions that you can use, depending on what you are actually displaying (use "Conditional Tags" to switch):

- Single post or page (or custom post): [`the_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date)
- Archives: Use the most current post date for this archive…
- …

Here's your plugin, slightly reformatted to retrieve the timezone name from the GMT offset, account for [PHP Bug #44780](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44780) (props [uınbɐɥs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11896631/376483)) and also custom settings from your admin UI. If that is not what you want, you will have to play a bit with the options. What is missing is the conditional switches

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: "Last Modified" meta tag */
add_action( 'wp_head', function() 
{
    // Abort if not on at home/ on the front page as this is just an example
    if ( ! ( is_home() or is_front_page() )
        return;

    $offset = get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * 3600;
    $zone = timezone_name_from_abbr( '', $offset, 1 );
    ! $zone and $zone = timezone_name_from_abbr( '', $offset, 0 );
    $format = get_option( 'date_format' ).' '.get_option( 'time_format' ) );
    // @TODO adjust to take post date or similar into account
    $date = 'now';

    printf( '<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="%s" />',
        ( new DateTime( $date, $zone ) )
            ->format( $format )
    );
} );
```

Comment: Code is tad off, DateTime doesn't take zone as first argument.

Comment: @Rarst Written out of the back of my head + SO answer. Thanks for the pointer – fixed.